# Stretch line spacing to fill page

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-spacing

I'm writing a thesis which has to be double spaced with a 12 point font size and with set margins. However, due to each page having different subsections, pictures etc., the text doesn't line up nicely with the bottom margin. I've included a minimum working example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[twoside,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.8cm,inner=4cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\doublespacing
\begin{document}

\section{Section title}
\lipsum[3-4]
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[6-7]
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[8-9]
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[9-14]

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to enable either the paragraph spacing or line spacing to stretch in order for the text to fill the entire vertical range on each page? I've been trying things like:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength\parindent{20pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip plus 8pt minus 8pt}
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Put `\flushbottom` just before `\begin{document}`. However, this idea (of aligning bottom line) may be bad.